# terraform module from git repo - how to exclude directories from being cloned by terraform init?

Tags: module, directory, terraform

We have a terraform module developed and kept it inside a repo and people access it by putting below in their main.tf

```
module "standard_ingress" {
   source = "git::https://xxx.xx.xx/scm/xxxx/xxxx-terraform-eks-ingress-module.git?ref=master"
```

When they do `terraform init` whole repo is being cloned to folder (~/.terraform/modules/standard_ingress)

We have some non module (non terraform) related folders as well in the same repo and same branch.
Is there a way, we can make terraform init exclude those folders being cloned.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude parts of the module? Would the exclusion be different per initialization?

Comment: Its not part of the module, lets say in the module repo I have some .tf files and a terratest folder. That terratest folder is not needed for the module to work.
Contents of the terratest folder is really for integration testing the module.

Comment: That certainly makes sense to not include `terratest`. Unfortunately, there is no `*.ignore` file for Terraform modules like there is for other release packages, but maybe there should be one? Seems like an interesting proposal for a feature request.

Comment: Thank you, I posted in hashicorp terraform community as well.  
Lets see if they accept it as feature request.

Answer (score 2):

[The Git transfer protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) all work by transferring batches of commits associated with a particular remote ref (branch or tag), so there is no way for a Git client to fetch only a subset of the directories or files in the selected commit.

Terraform can only use the Git protocol as it's already defined, and so it cannot provide any capabilities that the underlying protocol lacks.

If your concern is the amount of time taken to clone the entire repository, you may be able to optimize by excluding anything except the most recent commit rather than by ignoring files within that commit. You can do that by setting the `depth` argument to 1:

```
  source = "git::https://xxx.xx.xx/scm/xxxx/xxxx-terraform-eks-ingress-module.git?ref=master&depth=1"
```

If even that isn't sufficient then I think your only further option would be to add a separate build and release step for your modules where you capture the subset of files that are relevant to the Terraform modules into a `.zip` or `.tar.gz` archive, publish that archive somewhere that Terraform can fetch it over HTTP, and then use [fetching archives over HTTP](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/sources#http-urls) as the source type. In this case Terraform will download only the contents of the archive, allowing you to curate exactly what's included. (It would also be equivalent to put the archive into one of the supported cloud storage services, [such as Amazon S3](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/sources#s3-bucket).)